# What are the number of weight and bias parameters associated with this CNN?

Tags: deep-learning, conv-neural-network

What will be the number of weight and bias parameters associated with the convolutional layers in the following example?

Here we actually have just one convolutional layer with 2 filters for 3 different sizes (2,3,4).

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I identified the number of weight and bias parameters associated with the convolutional layer in the given figure.

For filter size = 4,

```
total weight parameters = 4 * 5 = 20
total bias parameters = 1
Since, total filters = 2, so total parameters = (4 * 5 + 1) * 2 = 42
```

Since the filter is of size 4, then from `4 x 5` matrix, we will get finally just one feature value. So, `kernel_value(1 x 20) x weight_param(20 x 1)` results in 1 feature value. Including 1 bias parameter, total parameters required is `(20 + 1) = 21`.

For filter size = 3,

```
total weight parameters = 3 * 5 = 15
total bias parameters = 1
Since, total filters = 2, so total parameters = (3 * 5 + 1) * 2 = 32
```

For filter size = 2,

```
total weight parameters = 2 * 5 = 10
total bias parameters = 1
Since, total filters = 2, so total parameters = (2 * 5 + 1) * 2 = 22
```

So, total weight and bias parameters = 42 + 32 + 22 = 96.